# Alternative query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there an alternative way to write this query?

```
select 
* 
from 
(select 
   countries.country_name, sum( profits.amount_sold) 
from 
   PROFITS 
full outer join 
   CUSTOMERS on PROFITS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID 
full outer join 
   COUNTRIES on CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY_ID = COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID 
WHERE 
   COUNTRY_NAME = 'Japan'   
group by 
   countries.country_name )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove outer `SELECT * FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the current query, it looks like the outer select is unnecessary.  Also, since you are aggregating over rows, you don't need full outer joins.  If you want a slightly different way to simplify the query, you should be able to use:

```
select countries.country_name, sum(profits.amount_sold)
from profits, customers, countries
where profits.cust_id = customers.cust_id
and customers.country_id = countries.country_id
and countries.country_name = 'Japan'
group by countries.country_name;
```

And finally, since your query filters to a single row (country_name='Japan'), you don't even need the group by, if you're sure that you have at least one row:

```
select 'Japan' as country_name, sum(profits.amount_sold)
from profits, customers, countries
where profits.cust_id = customers.cust_id
and customers.country_id = countries.country_id
and countries.country_name = 'Japan';
```

Comment: No, **don't** use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  Always explicitly qualify your joins (and include as many conditions as possible), as this makes them more understandable/readable.  Plus, when you do it this way, it's really easy to accidently turn it into a full Cartesian product by forgetting a condition (most RDBMSs throw errors for missing `ON` clauses).  Still, I suspect this is what the OP was actually intending...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Definitely a good point that explicit joins will always be better, since the explicit conditions both increase readability and gives optimizers better hinting for increased performance.  Good optimizers should make them equivalent, but not all DB systems have good optimizers.

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided any objective e.g faster, easier to read, easier to modify for other functions. I will assume you intend speed.

firstly, you can change the join on countries to a left join.  Finally you can remove the nest it is in as it also seems to serve no our purpose.

Comment: Look again - `Customers` is actually the cross-reference table between `Profits` and `Countries`.  The entire query hinges on that table.